# bug in pgfplots or other packages

Tags: tikz-pgf

This code lets pdflatex go into an infinite loop

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

% required for bug
\usepackage{onlyamsmath}
% required for tikzpicture
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}   
% changes error
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[name=plot1]
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[name=plot2,at={($(plot1.east)+(0cm,0)$)},anchor=west]
  \end{axis}     
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

after it reports this first error (actually the first error is something else but that is only because I reduced it to a minimal example)

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\next ->\@nil
```

Can somebody track the origin and or tell me a workaround?

Comment: You are missing a trailing `]` in the first empty `axis` environment. But it seems that `onlyamsmath` is having an issue with `$(plot1.east)+(0cm,0cm)$`. And you also need `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` to do coordinate calculations.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to put `egend style={at={($(plot1.east)+(0cm,0)$)}}` or something similar to your axis option.

Comment: My bad. I meant to type `legend style`.

Comment: @PeterGrill I corrected the missing `]`, but that was not the actual error. `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` is not needed for this error. One could add it, but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: @hpesoj626: This has nothing to do with legends. I align the axis next to each other. I only removed the whole plotting code because it is not relevant for the error.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech: `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` is needed as you are trying to do coordinate calculations. It doesn't _yet_ fix the problem as the problem is with `onlyamsmath`. But once the `onlyamsmath` issue is resolved, then you will  require `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` so might as well add it.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Ok, I included it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I debugged into your example:

This bug is an incompatibility between the TikZ `calc` library and `onlyamsmath`.

It is caused by the fact that onlyamsmath maliciously changes the meaning of `$` so that TikZ fails to parse the expression.

More precisely, `onlyamsmath` changes the catcode of `$` to active (code 13) and TikZ's `calc` library expects a standard math-mode dollar (code 3). I suggest you file a bug report for the author of `onlyamsmath`: in my humble opinion, changes to standard catcodes almost surely break compatibility with some other package.

I added a sanity check with a useful error message to TikZ in the CVS version such that it detects and reports the incompatibility problem.

Note that the problem is entirely unrelated to pgfplots:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

% required for bug
\usepackage{onlyamsmath}
% required for tikzpicture
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}   
% changes error
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\message{Catcode is \the\catcode`\$^^J}%

%\catcode`\$=3
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (plot1) at (0,0) {};

  \node [at={({$({plot1.east})+(0cm,0)$})},anchor=west]
  \end{axis}     
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you change the definition of the catcode and restore it afterwards?

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech that's error prone: it would work in some cases, but not in all (e.g. if the tikzpicture has been defined in some macro). And there is nothing that TikZ can do about it.

Comment: The latest CVS version of TikZ/PGF (2013/02/23) detects this situation. The log message says: _Added sanity check for the catcode of  `$` to avoid incompatibilities with `onlyamsmath` package._

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises due to two factors. First, `onlyamsmath` makes `$` active with definition

```
> $=macro:
->\ifx \protect \@typeset@protect \expandafter \futurelet \expandafter \next \e
xpandafter \checkdsp \else \expandafter $\fi .
```

Secondly, there is an `\edef` hidden in the start of the axis:

```
\tikz@scan@no@calculator #1(#2)->\edef \tikz@temp {(#2)}\expandafter \tikz@@sca
n@@no@calculator \expandafter #1\tikz@temp 
#1<-\pgfplots@set@at 
#2<-$(plot1.east
```

What therefore happens is that rather than do the `\futurelet`, the `\edef` tries to expand `\next`. The exact meaning depends on what it was last used for (hence the change of error if `siunitx` is loaded), but the problem is the same.

I'm not sure there is an obvious fix, as there are further assumptions about the behaviour of the argument of `at` within the `pgfplots` code.

Comment: Well, that was double-analysis :)  Note that the fact that TikZ's parsing ended up in `\tikz@scan@no@calculator` is already a follow-up problem because of the wrong `\catcode`.